# Is it possible to have a shader effect a specific area of a texture?

Tags: shaders

I want to have it so the shader effects only a specific part of the texture.
like for example, a white surface never getting darker when in darkness.
[image: Text]
And the white surfaces don't get covered by any cel shaded shaders. (Pictured here)

[image: Text]

I'm really new to blender, so please bear with me

Comment: In the Shader Editor, if you plug a (for example white) Emission shader in the Material Output it will stay the same color whatever is your lighting

Comment: It's true what Moonboots says, you have to use emission shader. But if the white parts are not different material (because the topology doesn't let it) you have to use a Mix Shader with a color mask as Alpha to blend the two shader.

Comment: @FFeller I don't know what a color mask is, please may you elaborate?

I work better with visuals, so perhaps a screenshot of the configuration and where the components are located would help?

Answer (score 1):

The Mix Shader can blend between two shaders. You can specify the area by a mask which is usually a black and white or a grayscale image. You can see on the right side you have to plug the mask to the "Fac" socket. The base shader (it's principled in my case but it can be anything) into the middle and the Emission into the last. The mask is the black and white umbrella in the UV editor. You have to make a black and white image about your texture or you can use your base color with a ColorRamp node.
[image]